# Выдает ошибку ValueError при запуске rfe = rfe.fit(train1[X], train1[y])

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

есть выборка 100000,392
пытаюсь выбрать столбцы для построения модели предсказания

```
train_vars=train1.columns.tolist()
y='target'
X=[i for i in train_vars if i not in y]
rfe = RFE(model, 20) 
rfe = rfe.fit(train1[X], train1[y]) 
print(rfe.support_) 
print(rfe.ranking_)
```

выдает ошибку

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-b2ce8d32a127> in <module>
      1 rfe = RFE(model, 20)
----> 2 rfe = rfe.fit(train1[X], train1[y])
      3 print(rfe.support_)
      4 print(rfe.ranking_)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: по-моему, ошибка достаточно понятно поясняет в чем проблема...

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен. Ошибка в наличии значений NaN в выборке данных.